# Rendering delay in loading the font from the "ms-appdata://" in win2d?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, win2d

I have requirement of loading the text on scroll, each text will be having different font and such texts are in 100's, while scrolling i will be fetching the fonts from the ms-appdata://, which is causing delay in rendering, is there any way to cache these font for the first load and then use them afterwards instead of fetching again by ms-appdata://

Comment: Have you tried place the font file in package foldre (`ms-appx:///`)

Comment: @NicoZhu actually i will be downloading the fonts at runtime as per the user requirement, to store the font files at runtime `ms-appx://` will only support read not write, so my only place to store the font files will be at the `ms-appdata://`

Comment: ok, actually the io speed will effect with you disk device, do you use ssd or hdd?

Comment: @NicoZhu  i7-11850H,2.50GHz with 512gb ssd

Comment: @NicoZhu, i will be downloading the font only once, when ever user opens app again i'll be fetching those fonts

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] to help us check the question?